# Removing .DS_Store from git repo

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository, jupyter-lab

I keep getting both a .DS_Store file and a .ipynb_checkpoints folder everytime I push to my git repository. I've tried creating a .gitignore file, but they still don't go away when I do another commit.
I have tried:

```
touch .gitignore
% echo '.ipynb_checkpoints' >> ~/.gitignore
```

```
echo .DS_Store >> .gitignore
```

Any help on how to remove these from the front page of my git?

Comment: `.DS_Store` files are created by MacOS Finder. If you're on MacOS and allow Finder to look in a directory, you'll get this file. If you've *committed* the file, it's now in the Git commits. No existing commit can ever be changed; at most, you can remove it and keep it out of *future* commits (including any commits you make to replace the existing ones that have the file). The `.ipynb_checkpoints` file is similar but comes from IPython Notebook (as used by Jupyter). See VonC's answer below for making sure they're not in *future* commits.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you remove them from your Git repository first, while keeping them on your disk

```
git rm -r --cached .DS_Store
git rm --cached .ipynb_checkpoints

git commit -m "Remove ignored files"
```

Then you won't see them in your next commit, and the `.gitignore` will apply.